# Installation of BLOCKBENCH framework

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

Does anyone know how to install [BLOCKBENCH: A Framework for Analyzing Private Blockchains.](https://github.com/ooibc88/blockbench)?

Comment: Hi there. The README file points to the instructions for setting things up for Ethereum: https://github.com/ooibc88/blockbench/tree/master/benchmark/ethereum

Comment: I didn't find installation guide there.

Comment: Did you succeed in configuring and running blockbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked the original repo and made some improvements for running the kvstore benchmark for ethereum. My write-up on how I use the fork to run the benchmark can be found on medium: https://medium.com/@mu7eh7/running-blockbench-for-ethereum-6dca3ed44a35

If you want to use the original repo, you will have to do the following:

1. Checkout the README files e.g. in the /src and [/benchmark/ethereum](https://github.com/ooibc88/blockbench/tree/master/benchmark/ethereum)
2. Compile/prepare the benchmark client(s) that you want to use, they can be found in the [/src](https://github.com/ooibc88/blockbench/tree/master/src) folder, e.g. build https://github.com/ooibc88/blockbench/tree/master/src/macro/kvstore by (preparing the dependencies and) running `make` (my fork contains a Dockerfile that installs all dependencies into a container)
3. Modify the benchmark scripts and parameters in the [/benchmark/ethereum](https://github.com/ooibc88/blockbench/tree/master/benchmark/ethereum) folder (the scripts contain e.g. a hard-coded username and the parameters in the env.sh file need to be adjusted to your setup.